# Logging CakePHP 3 exceptions to database

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm developing an API which throws various exceptions on bad requests, internal errors, etc..

I'd like to log these exceptions to a log table I've built. I could do this above each throw, but I assume Cake has a way of consolidating this into a custom exception handler. I just can't figure it out from the documentation http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html

Can someone point me to a resource I've failed to find or throw me some sample code?

Edit: Preference is to log to file as well as database.

Comment: You can use the [DatabaseLog](https://github.com/dereuromark/CakePHP-DatabaseLog) plugin, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all there in the docs:

- [Logging Exceptions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html#logging-exceptions)
- [Logging](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html) (read the whole chapter)
- [Creating Loggers (Log to DB, includes Example!)](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html#creating-log-adapters)
- [Implementation of the logger from the book](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-database-log)